# How can I save a row vector to HDF in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, hdf5

For some reason, the `hdf5write` method in MATLAB is automatically converting my row vectors to column vectors when I re-read them:

```
>> hdf5write('/tmp/data.h5','/data',rand(1,10));
>> size(hdf5read('/tmp/data.h5','/data'))

ans =

    10     1
```

However, for a row vector in the third dimension, it comes back just fine:

```
>> hdf5write('/tmp/data.h5','/data',rand(1,1,10));
>> size(hdf5read('/tmp/data.h5','/data'))

ans =

     1     1    10
```

How can I get `hdf5write` to do the right thing for row vectors? They should be coming back as 1 x 10, not 10 x 1.

**edit** the problem is slightly more complicated because I am using c-based mex to actually read the data later, instead of `hdf5read`. Moreover, the problem *really* is in `hdf5write`, and this is visible in the hdf5 files themselves:

```
>> hdf5write('/tmp/data.h5','/data',randn(1,10));
>> ! h5ls /tmp/data.h5

data                     Dataset {10}
```

that is, the data is saved as a 1-dimensional array in the hdf5 file. For comparison, I try the same thing with an actual 2-d matrix (to show what it looks like), a 1-d column vector, a 1-d vector along the third dimension, and, for kicks, try the `V71Dimensions` trick which is in the help for both `hdf5read` and `hdf5write`:

```
>> hdf5write('/tmp/data.h5','/data',randn(10,1)); %1-d col vector
>> ! h5ls /tmp/data.h5

data                     Dataset {10}
>> hdf5write('/tmp/data.h5','/data',randn(1,1,10)); %1-d vector along 3rd dim; annoying
>> ! h5ls /tmp/data.h5

data                     Dataset {10, 1, 1}
>> hdf5write('/tmp/data.h5','/data',randn(2,5)); %2-d matrix. notice the reversal in dim order
>> ! h5ls /tmp/data.h5

data                     Dataset {5, 2}
>> hdf5write('/tmp/data.h5','/data',randn(1,10),'V71Dimensions',true); %1-d row; option does not help
>> ! h5ls /tmp/data.h5

data                     Dataset {10}
```

So, the problem does seem to be in `hdf5write`. The `'V71Dimensions'` flag does not help: the resultant hdf5 file is still a Dataset {10} instead of a Dataset {10,1}.

Answer (score 4):

It's the reading that's an issue. From the [help](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/hdf5read.html)

> [...] = hdf5read(..., 'V71Dimensions',
>   BOOL) specifies whether to change the
>   majority of data sets read from the
>   file. If BOOL is true, hdf5read
>   permutes the first two dimensions of
>   the data set, as it did in previous
>   releases (MATLAB 7.1 [R14SP3] and
>   earlier). This behavior was intended
>   to account for the difference in how
>   HDF5 and MATLAB express array
>   dimensions. HDF5 describes data set
>   dimensions in row-major order; MATLAB
>   stores data in column-major order.
>   However, permuting these dimensions
>   may not correctly reflect the intent
>   of the data and may invalidate
>   metadata. When BOOL is false (the
>   default), the data dimensions
>   correctly reflect the data ordering as
>   it is written in the file — each
>   dimension in the output variable
>   matches the same dimension in the
>   file.

Thus:

```
hdf5write('/tmp/data.h5','/data',rand(1,10));
size(hdf5read('/tmp/data.h5','/data','V71Dimensions',true))
ans =
     1    10
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm affraid for this you will have to use the low-level HDF5 API of Matlab.

In Matlab, the low-level API is available using for instance `H5.open(...)`, `H5D.write(...)` and so on. The names correspond exactly to those of the C library (see the [HDF5 doc](http://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/RM/RM_H5Front.html)). However there is a slight difference in the arguments they take, but the matlab `help` function will tell you everything you need to know...

The good news is that the Matlab version of the API is still less verbose than the C version. For instance, you don't have to close manually the datatypes, dataspaces, etc. since Matlab closes them for you when the variables go out of scope.